# modules: how to force version of dependent lib

Tags: go, go-modules

Overall go modules works just like the docs say. But, in one case, a dependent lib's latest tag is v1.3.0 which go mod tidy finds. However I need v1.1.0. No matter what I do (hand edit go.mod, go get -u) 'go build' merely reverts the version right back to v1.3.0 which breaks the build. Indeed, the whole point of modules is setting the dependencies: so how? Go get should set it permanently but it doesn't stay set. Using go1.13.5

Comment: Have you tried running `go get the/package@v1.1.0`? See [Go Wiki: Modules: How to Upgrade and Downgrade Dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ... And Yes I have ... Sure enough go.mod reads v1.1.0. but go build puts back 1.3.0. I'm beginning to think maybe an env var is wrong b/c what you wrote really should done the trick.

Comment: Is this an indirect dependency?

Answer (score 4):

> No matter what I do (hand edit go.mod, go get -u) ...

After you modify the version of the dependency in the `go.mod` file, then what you need to do is perform `go mod tidy` command (from your explanation I assume you haven't done it).

Example:

```
# modify the dependency version on go.mod, then
go mod tidy
```

If you use vendoring then you also need to run the `go mod vendor` command to update the downloaded dependencies inside `vendor/` folder.

```
# modify the dependency version on go.mod, then
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

Comment: Why do you have `go mod vendor` there?

Comment: @zerkms if the vendor folder is there, then dependencies inside will be updated

Comment: Sure, but it's not obvious whether OP uses vendoring (or more correctly: there are signs they don't)